# Priors on matrix determinant

Tags: covariance, matrix, bayes, hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior

I have a positive semi definite matrix (covariance matrix). Was wondering are there any distributions that can place a prior on the determinant?

Something along lines of $$\exp(-k|X|)$$

Note that the matrix gamma distribution is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you asking if their are any standard priors that incorporate a determinant?

Comment: @Bab This is a Bayesian question: the OP wants to make inferences about the distribution of a covariance matrix based on a prior distribution of its determinant.  Sachin, you have already answered your question: of course you can place a prior on the determinant (although the example you wrote down is neither a CDF nor a PDF except when $k=1$). Perhaps what you are really wondering is whether there are any *analytically convenient* priors that will make Bayesian updating easy. Because updating depends on the presumed distribution of the matrix itself, what can you tell us about that?

Comment: At Bab. Yep. Exactly what I'm asking. @whubber Basically I want to push the inverse covariance towards sparsity. Only problem with above is that I don't know what the normalising constant is.

Comment: What is the connection between the determinant and the sparsity level of your matrix? I don't see why they would be related.

Comment: @bnaul It's related to sparse inverse covariance estimation. The higher the penalty on the determinant of inverse covariance, $-k|X|^{-1}$ the higher the sparsity. This is a frequentist approach, wondering if Bayesian approach is possible.